# div or asp:Panel background image

Tags: asp.net, css, html, panel

I am trying to get a background image to display in the bottom right corner of a div (or asp:panel) but I believe that the display:inline-block is causing it to not show. That is required because I have multiple boxes horizontally aligned on the screen (without it they display vertically).

css:

```
.showIcon{
            background: url('Images/icon.png') no-repeat right bottom;
            display: inline-block;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #808080;
        }
```

Is there something wrong with the css?
I do have a table displayed within each div, can that be the reason?

Comment: Is your Images folder where you keep your CSS file?

Comment: If you need to reference the Images folder from site root, it should be '/images/icon.png'

Comment: Please post your asp or html so we can see where the issue is. I do not believe there is a problem with that css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code. And also as you asked, no table won't make any difference.

See this fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/3V8m9/2/

The only thing I added is the dimensions: `height: 100px; width: 100px;` to illustrate.

There can be two scenarios. One, either your image path is not correct. Two, width/height may not be adequate enough.

Comment: The table is actually being drawn on top it seems. By setting the cell/tables css property it displays just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe display:inline-block is the issue. You can always use float left to align each against each other.

**CSS**

```
.showIcon{
        background: url('Images/icon.png') no-repeat right bottom;
        float: left;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #808080;
    } code here
```